# Scrapy/Python request priority and CONCURRENT_REQUESTS

Tags: python, scrapy

I am scraping a single domain which has a single IP. It has a list of store URLs and each store URL has a list of products (multi-page)

First I go through store URLs and yield requests while assigning a priority which goes smaller for each store. Store 1 gets -1, Store 2 gets -2 etc.

When loading next page of product list URLs, I assign the same priority to the request.

This all works fine when `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` are set. I get URLs with priority -1 and -2 loaded one after another. Scrapy does not progress to URLs with priority -3 or lower.

However, I tried `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN` and `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP` and these ends up URLs with priority -1, -2, -3, -4 loaded.

I would like to understand why `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` work differently than `...PER_DOMAIN` and `...PER_IP` options as I am downloading from a single domain with single IP address.

Can anybody explain this?

Here is sample code to see how it fails:

```
from scrapy.spiders import Spider, Request
import scrapy
import logging

class MySpider(Spider):

    custom_settings = {
        'DEPTH_STATS_VERBOSE': True,
#        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 1,
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 1,
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP': 1,
        'AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY': 1,
    }

    name = 'toscrapecom'
    start_urls = ['http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-1.html']

    urls1 = (
        'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-{}.html'.format(i + 1) for i in range(5)
    )

    urls2 = (
        'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-{}.html'.format(i + 1) for i in range(5,10)
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        reqPriority = 20
        for url in self.urls1:
            yield Request(url,priority=reqPriority,callback=self.next_page)
            logging.info("%s Priority %s URL %s", self.name, reqPriority, url)
            reqPriority = reqPriority - 1

    def next_page(self,response):
        reqPriority = 40
        for url in self.urls2:
            yield Request(url,priority=reqPriority)
            logging.info("%s Priority %s URL %s", self.name, reqPriority, url)
            reqPriority = reqPriority - 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Request priority does not ensure order.

If you have 16 requests, each with a different priority, and a `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN` of `16`, all 16 requests are sent almost simultaneously, and they are parsed in the order they come from the server, which is unlikely to match their priority value.

`CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` and `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN` actually work in combination. `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN` is 8 by default, and not defining `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN` is equivalent to defining it with `8` as value. If you are seeing a different behavior when setting `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN`, that must be because you used a value other than `8`.

`CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP`, it differs from `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN` as the name suggests. If defined, the value of `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN` is ignored.

Comment: You may be right, but I feel that when high priority responses go deeper there will be more high priority requests queued. Yet I do not see that only high priority requests are executed, after a while...

I define all the `CONCURRENT_*` options but if I just comment out `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` scrapy seems to work differently. I can see from debug output that all fetched requests are from same domain and that domain has a single IP but still.... Anyway, I voted your response up...

Comment: I added sample code, you can see how setting `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` effect the crawling order...